# Center Text within Row

Tags: dart, flutter

**Remark**: I just solved my problem by using [ListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) instead of my implementation (I am new to Flutter and did not know that something like that exists). But it would be still good to see how you solve the problem.

---

I have problems centering the `Text` within a `Row`. This is the code of my `IconRow` widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IconRow extends StatelessWidget {
  Icon _icon;
  Widget _widget;

  IconRow(Icon _icon, Widget _widget) {
    this._icon = _icon;
    this._widget = _widget;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
    child: new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
        this._icon,
        new Expanded(
            child: new Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0), child: this._widget))
      ]
    ));
  }
}
```

I use it like this within padding and other widgets:

```
new IconRow(
    new Icon(Icons.date_range),
    new Text(
        this._preparationStep.date,
        maxLines: 3,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
));
```

The result is shown in the image below. The Text is top aligned as you can see in the following image. The second text looks a lot better because it is a multiline text. The row is colored in red to visualize the spacing of the row.

[image: Flutter Text Top Aligned]

I already tried to change the `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` to `CrossAxisAlignment.center` which centered the text as wanted, but also moved the image to the center of the row as visualized in the following image.

[image: Flutter Image Centered]

How can i center the `Text` while the `Icon` is still top aligned?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Icon` into an `Align`

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
     child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
    ),
    Text("Foo")
  ],
)
```

Comment: That has no effect. I guess the problem is that the Icon just has the size of the image (not of the row). Centering the icon just for the image results in no visual change. I just used new Center(...).

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted to center the icon. I changed my example. The solution is the same though

Comment: `Alignment.topCenter` moves the text to the center horizontally, but i require vertically. The effect of a horizontal centering can also be accomplished by setting the `textAlign` property of the text. However i tried with `Alignment.centerLeft` (which should be the right value) and it is also not working.